# Do you know how to toss imageview into other view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imageview

I have a `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewCell`s. The collection view cells contain one `UIImageView` each. When the user taps on one of the cells I want to show the same image in another view. How can I pass the image into the next view?

Comment: What do you mean by toss into another view?

Comment: yes that's right!

Comment: I have edited the question to make it easier to understand, but you should include your attempts so far as well.

Answer (score 0):

simple, just pass it whenever you make an route to second controller

```
.........
let vc2: <#your controller#> = <#your controller#>()
vc2.image = self.image
vc1.show(vc2)
// or make your router
..........
```

and retreive your image variable

```
.......
self.imageView.image = self.image
......
```

you may need to declare an variable first in vc2 , then you can `toss` it to next ViewController